# <![CDATA[Message data ...]]> is showing as &lt;![CDATA[MESSAGE CONTENT DATA]]&gt;

Tags: xml, cdata

I am trying to build the payload/message body for an element. According to
 the specific the payload has to be within a CDATA element. I tried to do
 this as shown below

```
private static final String START_TAG=new String("<![CDATA[");
private static final String END_TAG= new String("]]>");
```

This does not seem to work as the message is coming out as shown below

```
<![CDATA[MESSAGE CONTENT DATA]]>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

how I can keep the output as `<![CDATA[Message data ...]]>`

Comment: This is happening because you seem to be using strings to build XML. You should use string APIs to work with strings, and XML APIs to work with XML. Consider learning [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Comment: Your description does not match your title.  What is the real problem?